# How to close a JFrame without closing others

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to display three `JFrame` objects at the same time.
When I close one of them from the up corner, the other frames should still be visible but they're not! 
I searched for it and I just got that the problem is related to these:

- `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`
- `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

How can I do that?

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) But having said that, `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` should 'wrok' for this.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556) to see it work.

Comment: Can you show what are you trying  to do?

Comment: What went wrong when you tried `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` ?  I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: there is a frame ,clicking a button opens an other frame . when i close one of these frames from the close icon at the corner of the screen , both of frames will close . but i just want one of them closed .

Comment: the point is i don't know where to type setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: Oh, OK.  Well, I'm assuming you've got a class that extends `JFrame`, and gives it the features that you want.  You could write that line of code somewhere in the constructor for that class.

Answer (score 2):

Are you extending `JFrame`? Don't.

Also when you inherit `JFrame`, the CLOSE operation gets defined for every 
window you create, so it will cause termination of window.

I din't had any issues with the following code :

```
 JFrame j1=new JFrame();
 JFrame j2=new JFrame();
 JFrame j3=new JFrame();

 j1.setVisible(true);
 j2.setVisible(true);
 j3.setVisible(true);

 j1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
 j2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
 j3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

**EDIT:**

*"Where should i type this"*

Where ever it suits you.What I can think(from your closing problem) you are having as structure something like :

```
public class FooClass extends JFrame {

   FooClass()
    {

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new FooClass().setVisible(true);
        new FooClass().setVisible(true);
        new FooClass().setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Don't force your class to extend `JFrame`, rather create the object as shown above 
And use '.' operator to preform functions `JSomeObject.SetThis...();`

**EDIT 2:**

Or just see if `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)` helps you.

OR

You can add a window listener and call `setVisible(false)` on `JFrame` :

```
 addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
    setVisible(false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Where should i type this?

Comment: you mean in the first page code? or in every code ? after main ? or before main ?

Comment: Everywhere in your code.

Comment: See my new edit about using hide on close.